# Unable to Install SQL Server 2012 on Windows 7 PC - cabinet file .cab has an invalid digital signature

Tags: installation, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2012 on my windows 7 PC and i can never get past this error:

The following error has occurred:

> Error 1330.A file that is required cannot be installed because the cabinet file D:\1033_ENU_LP\redist\VisualStudioShell\VSSetup\cab6.cab has an invalid digital signature.  This may indicate that the cabinet file is corrupt.

followed by:

> The following error has occurred:
>
> Error reading from file D:\1033_ENU_LP\x64\setup\sql2008support\PFiles\SqlServr\100\Setup\Release\x64\jvudfl73.dll.  Verify that the file exists and that you can access it.

**Installation Package:**

I downloaded the source from Microsoft's Student Dreamspark program website and burnt the ISO file to a DVD and installed from there.

**Computer Info:**

[image]
[image]

**Installation Details:**

[image: Install highlights]

[image: Errors]

Error Log:

```
Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Failed: see details below
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2068052686
  Start time:                    2013-12-23 10:32:11
  End time:                      2013-12-23 10:43:50
  Requested action:              Install

Setup completed with required actions for features.
Troubleshooting information for those features:
  Next step for Adv_SSMS:        Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Next step for Conn:            Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Next step for SSMS:            Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Next step for SQLEngine:       Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Next step for DQ:              Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Next step for FullText:        Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Next step for Replication:     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.


Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  LST-PC
  Machine processor count:       2
  OS version:                    Windows 7
  OS service pack:               Service Pack 1
  OS region:                     United States
  OS language:                   English (United States)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered 
  SQL Server 2012                                                          LocalDB                                  1033                 Express Edition      11.1.3000.0     No        

Package properties:
  Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 1
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2012
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       11
  SPLevel:                       0
  Installation location:         D:\x64\setup\
  Installation edition:          Standard

Product Update Status:
  None discovered.

User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        Install
  ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      false
  AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\SQLAgent$LST
  AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****
  AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Manual
  ASBACKUPDIR:                   Backup
  ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
  ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config
  ASDATADIR:                     Data
  ASLOGDIR:                      Log
  ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1
  ASSERVERMODE:                  MULTIDIMENSIONAL
  ASSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  ASSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            <empty>
  ASTEMPDIR:                     Temp
  BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Automatic
  CLTCTLRNAME:                   <empty>
  CLTRESULTDIR:                  <empty>
  CLTSTARTUPTYPE:                0
  CLTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
  CLTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  CLTWORKINGDIR:                 <empty>
  COMMFABRICENCRYPTION:          0
  COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL:        0
  COMMFABRICPORT:                0
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20131223_103058\ConfigurationFile.ini
  CTLRSTARTUPTYPE:               0
  CTLRSVCACCOUNT:                <empty>
  CTLRSVCPASSWORD:               <empty>
  CTLRUSERS:                     <empty>
  ENABLERANU:                    false
  ENU:                           true
  ERRORREPORTING:                false
  FEATURES:                      SQLENGINE, REPLICATION, FULLTEXT, DQ, CONN, SSMS, ADV_SSMS
  FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
  FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           <empty>
  FTSVCACCOUNT:                  NT Service\MSSQLFDLauncher$LST
  FTSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  HELP:                          false
  IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  true
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              false
  INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             <empty>
  INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTANCEID:                    LST
  INSTANCENAME:                  LST
  ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT:         0
  MATRIXCMSERVERNAME:            <empty>
  MATRIXNAME:                    <empty>
  NPENABLED:                     0
  PID:                           *****
  QUIET:                         false
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   false
  ROLE:                          <empty>
  RSINSTALLMODE:                 DefaultNativeMode
  RSSHPINSTALLMODE:              DefaultSharePointMode
  RSSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  RSSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  SAPWD:                         *****
  SECURITYMODE:                  SQL
  SQLBACKUPDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLCOLLATION:                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\MSSQL$LST
  SQLSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic
  SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           LST-PC\LST
  SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQLUSERDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQMREPORTING:                  false
  TCPENABLED:                    1
  UIMODE:                        Normal
  UpdateEnabled:                 true
  UpdateSource:                  MU
  X86:                           false

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20131223_103058\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Management Tools - Complete
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server 2008 Setup Support Files
  Component error code:          1305
  Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20131223_103058\SqlSupport_KatmaiRTM_Cpu64_1.log
  Error description:             Error reading from file D:\1033_ENU_LP\x64\setup\sql2008support\PFiles\SqlServr\100\Setup\Release\x64\jvudfl73.dll.  Verify that the file exists and that you can access it.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=11.0.3128.0&EvtType=SqlSupport.msi%40InstallFiles%401305

  Feature:                       Client Tools Connectivity
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server 2008 Setup Support Files
  Component error code:          1305
  Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20131223_103058\SqlSupport_KatmaiRTM_Cpu64_1.log
  Error description:             Error reading from file D:\1033_ENU_LP\x64\setup\sql2008support\PFiles\SqlServr\100\Setup\Release\x64\jvudfl73.dll.  Verify that the file exists and that you can access it.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=11.0.3128.0&EvtType=SqlSupport.msi%40InstallFiles%401305

  Feature:                       Management Tools - Basic
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server 2008 Setup Support Files
  Component error code:          1305
  Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20131223_103058\SqlSupport_KatmaiRTM_Cpu64_1.log
  Error description:             Error reading from file D:\1033_ENU_LP\x64\setup\sql2008support\PFiles\SqlServr\100\Setup\Release\x64\jvudfl73.dll.  Verify that the file exists and that you can access it.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=11.0.3128.0&EvtType=SqlSupport.msi%40InstallFiles%401305

  Feature:                       Database Engine Services
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server 2008 Setup Support Files
  Component error code:          1305
  Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20131223_103058\SqlSupport_KatmaiRTM_Cpu64_1.log
  Error description:             Error reading from file D:\1033_ENU_LP\x64\setup\sql2008support\PFiles\SqlServr\100\Setup\Release\x64\jvudfl73.dll.  Verify that the file exists and that you can access it.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=11.0.3128.0&EvtType=SqlSupport.msi%40InstallFiles%401305

  Feature:                       Data Quality Services
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server 2008 Setup Support Files
  Component error code:          1305
  Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20131223_103058\SqlSupport_KatmaiRTM_Cpu64_1.log
  Error description:             Error reading from file D:\1033_ENU_LP\x64\setup\sql2008support\PFiles\SqlServr\100\Setup\Release\x64\jvudfl73.dll.  Verify that the file exists and that you can access it.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=11.0.3128.0&EvtType=SqlSupport.msi%40InstallFiles%401305

  Feature:                       Full-Text and Semantic Extractions for Search
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server 2008 Setup Support Files
  Component error code:          1305
  Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20131223_103058\SqlSupport_KatmaiRTM_Cpu64_1.log
  Error description:             Error reading from file D:\1033_ENU_LP\x64\setup\sql2008support\PFiles\SqlServr\100\Setup\Release\x64\jvudfl73.dll.  Verify that the file exists and that you can access it.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=11.0.3128.0&EvtType=SqlSupport.msi%40InstallFiles%401305

  Feature:                       SQL Server Replication
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server 2008 Setup Support Files
  Component error code:          1305
  Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20131223_103058\SqlSupport_KatmaiRTM_Cpu64_1.log
  Error description:             Error reading from file D:\1033_ENU_LP\x64\setup\sql2008support\PFiles\SqlServr\100\Setup\Release\x64\jvudfl73.dll.  Verify that the file exists and that you can access it.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=11.0.3128.0&EvtType=SqlSupport.msi%40InstallFiles%401305

Rules with failures:

Global rules:

Scenario specific rules:

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20131223_103058\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
```

Comment: Did you try re downloading the installer and trying again?

Comment: @user1336827 Yes, same error :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

per MSDN:

The common workaround is to redownload the media and copy the setup locally on the hard drive and then run the installation

Comment: wow, this worked..how strange.. but thanks, accepted and upvoted :)